# store polygons and geometry in postgis

Tags: python, postgresql, geometry, postgis, blender

I'm hardly trying to extract data o polygons from Blender to PostGIS via Python. For the beginning I'm trying all this stuff with a simple cube. 
At all I want to get a pure POLYGON - GEOMETRY-Type in PostGIS which looks like 
POLYGON((x1 y1 z1, x2 y2 z2,.....))
I can read information from Blender in this way:

The vectors:

```
verts=[ 
<Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000)> ,
<Vector (1.0000, -1.0000, -1.0000)> ,
<Vector (-1.0000, -1.0000, -1.0000)> ,
<Vector (-1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000)> ,
<Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000)> ,
<Vector (1.0000, -1.0000, 1.0000)> ,
<Vector (-1.0000, -1.0000, 1.0000)> ,
<Vector (-1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000)> ,
 ]
```

and the faces (the numbers are the vertices which form a polygon):

```
faces = [
(0, 1, 2, 3)
(4, 7, 6, 5)
(0, 4, 5, 1)
(1, 5, 6, 2)
(2, 6, 7, 3)
(4, 0, 3, 7)
]
```

Now I don't know how to get this information into a POLYGON-GEOMETRY-structure to store it in PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

In the end I want a POLYGON((...)) for each face of the cube. And I want to do this for more complex 3D-models out of Blender. With POLYGON- or TIN-GEOMETRY.... But at first I need to know how to interact with the geometries with Python.

I hope you can get me a little further. I'm thankful for any hint.
Thanks!
J

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure about the Blender's internal object model so I have created some dummy data for that. But I think the end result should be close to what you are looking for:

```
verts = [[1.0,-1.0,0.0]]*8
faces = [
    (0, 1, 2, 3),
    (4, 7, 6, 5),
    (0, 4, 5, 1),
    (1, 5, 6, 2),
    (2, 6, 7, 3),
    (4, 0, 3, 7),
]

# ---------------------------------------------
# PostGIS POLYGON data formatting happens next

for f in faces:
    print("POLYGON((", end="")
    for point in f:
        v = verts[point]
        print("{} {} {} ".format(v[0], v[1], v[2]), end="")
    print("))")

# Will print....

# POLYGON((1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 ))
# POLYGON((1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 ))
# POLYGON((1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 ))
# POLYGON((1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 ))
# POLYGON((1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 ))
# POLYGON((1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 ))
```

Comment: thanks for answering!! I checked it and it really kinda look like the thing i wanted but it just looks like. at all I want to know how is this geometry-format POLYGON or TIN working in postgis? I want the call the EWKT-code for POLYGON/TIN. How can I write sth into it in the right way....!? I'll try a little further, but your answer helped me, good code! thanks ... :)

Comment: And actually I expected sth like this to write in the geometry of POLYGONS:
GeomFromEWKT('POLYGON((x1 y1 z1, x2 y2 z2,....))'3004) 
But how to make to loop that all points, however how much, are going to be stored in one Polygon-Geometry? THANKS